# Why is the view path /slug:slug/slug:url/ doesn't find django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, django-urls

I’m trying to understand why my page at 127.0.0.1/* manganame / * numberchaper does not open. Error 404, path / * manganame / * numberchaper not found. The path / * manganame / opens correctly, there I display links to the passage to the chapter. I keep chapters in the Add_chapters model. Why does not it work?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from . import views
from django.conf.urls import url




extra_patterns = [
    path("<slug:url>/", views.ChapterDetailView.as_view()),
    path("", views.ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='manga_index'),
]


urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.Get_list.as_view()),
    path('<str:slug>/', include(extra_patterns)),


 ]
```

models.py

```
class Manga(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("Название", max_length=100)
    another_name = models.CharField("Другие названия", max_length=150, default="")
    description = models.TextField("Описание")
    poster = models.ImageField("Постер", upload_to="manga/")
    part = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Томов", default="0")
    chapter = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Глав", default="0")
    year = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("год выпуска", default="")
    author = models.ManyToManyField(Author, verbose_name="Авторы", related_name="manga_author")
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre, verbose_name="Жанры")
    artist = models.ManyToManyField(Artist, verbose_name="Художники")
    manga_shots = models.ImageField("Изображения", upload_to="manga_shots/")
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category, verbose_name="Категория", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=130, unique=True)

class Add_chapter(models.Model):
    chapter_name = models.ForeignKey(
        Manga, verbose_name="Манга", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, max_length=100, default=""
    )
    volume = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Том", default="0")
    date_upd = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    chapter = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField("Глава", unique=True)
    files = models.FileField("Глава", upload_to=user_directory_path)
    url = models.SlugField(max_length=130, unique=True, default="")
```

views.py

```
class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Manga
    template_name = "mangaHTML/article_detail.html"
    slug_field = "url"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["manga_chapter"] = Add_chapter.objects.all()
        return context

class ChapterDetailView(DetailView):
    template_name = "mangaHTML/chapter_view.html"
    model = Add_chapter
    slug_field = "url"
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: format correctly URLs in question - I don't understand `127.0.0.1/* manganame / * numberchaper` - what means `*` in urls ? do you use spaces in urls ?

Comment: you don't have pattern for `/slug:slug/slug:url/` - only for `slug:slug/` or `slug:url/`

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem. Fixed "extra_patterns = [
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.ChapterDetailView.as_view())" and it works!  "*" means that any manga name or number chapter